# AngularJS $scope error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am receiving a JavaScript scope error when I execute this code -

```
        function processSuccess() {
            $scope.editForm.$dirty = false;
            vm.updateStatus = true;
            onRouteChangeOff(); //Stop listening for location changes
//            $location.path("/dashboard");
            $window.history.back();
        }
```

If I don't do the `$windows.history.back()` call and use the `$location.path`, I have no errors.  The problem that I am attempting to solve is that the user can get to this controllers view from two different paths and I need to send the user back to the original path.  Is there a better way or how do I fix this?

Error is -
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Comment: What's the error? Inf digest?

Comment: the error is -0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Comment: Not sure what the solution is - I just know Angular SPA doesn't play to nice with the history API

Comment: Do you have anything else running in application in this moment? Or in other words - can u reproduce this error in 3page example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code from another question and the error went away -

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $window.history.back();
},100);
```

From what I read, AngularJS does not like the #windows.history.back call.